# Can Polymer's web-component-tester use the Chai API?

Tags: polymer, chai, polymer-2.x, web-component-tester

I have this fixture that stamps out `<page-welcome>`:

```
<test-fixture id="fixture-one">
    <template>
        <page-welcome></page-welcome>
    </template>
</test-fixture>
```

Within `<page-welcome>`, I import `<paper-button>` and give it a class of `big-btn`. It's important this button exists on the `<page-welcome>` element, so I want to test it with:

```
    test('does the custom cmponent exist', function() {
        var test = fixture('fixture-one').shadowRoot.querySelector('.big-btn');
        assert.exists(test);
    });
```

It's  my understanding that I should be able to use all of the Chai API, and therefore `assert.exists` should be available.

But why do I get the following error?

```
assert.exists is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`web-component-tester` [uses `chai` 3.5.0](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/blob/4b36ac8/bower.json#L31), which does not include `assert.exists`.

Note that `chai`'s git history shows the introduction of `assert.exists` in `4.0.0-canary-2` (it seems undocumented in the release notes). You can install this version of `chai` as a `devDependency` without breaking anything:

```
bower i -D chai
```

Select the newer/4.x version (currently `4.0.2`) when bower prompts for version resolution:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for chai, please choose one by typing one of the numbers below:
    1) chai#^3.2.0 which resolved to 3.5.0 and is required by web-component-tester#6.0.0
    2) chai#^4.0.2 which resolved to 4.0.2

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json

? Answer
```